# Vimeo API Auto-pause at certain time

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

I am wondering if vimeo a JavaScript API allows for the video to auto - pause at a certain point in playback ( eg after the video has been playing for 55 seconds)- and then wait for the user to click on the video to resume playback.

Any help would be great as I am very new to JavaScript.

Here is the vimeo js website: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Using the embedded Flash player, something like this should work:

```
document.getElementById('vimeo_player').api_addEventListener('play', function(event) {
    window.setTimeout('document.getElementById("vimeo_player").pause()', 55000);
})
```